# Private memory address vs OpenProcess

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

I understand that every process in Windows has its own private-memory-address which is protected area that prevent to write over others memory. Windows guarantees that **ASLR** and private memory will stay safe.

But according to **Windows Internals Chapter 1**:

`the debugger simply opens the process with OpenProcess, this allows you change memory in the target process`.

So whats the point of private memory? there is no sand-boxing ? or windows just deny its doc them self ?

Comment: You can't just open arbitrary processes and alter them. You need *permissions* to do that. Windows has a security system to help prevent unauthorized alterations of processes. For instance, you usually need admin rights to write to other processes. But a debugger usually has permission to alter the process it is debugging, if you have sufficient rights to attach a debugger in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau its just `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` flag and a administrator account which can bypass easily

Comment: non-admins typically can't use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, the operation will fail with an "access denied" error.

Comment: A local administrator account can get privileges that allow it to read a process' memory. The protection is that regular users cannot log in as an administrator.

Comment: [airtight hatchways](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283) , although "the case" is different, the principle applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that each process having its own address space prevents accidental interference by other processes. It is not intended to be absolute proof against inspection or modification. This is simply one of those usefulness-versus-security tradeoffs.

Note also that a user normally does not have permission to open processes that are part of other windows sessions. (They can only do that if they have the debugging privilege. Privileges are another usefulness-versus-security tradeoff, they allow normally forbidden actions without reference to security descriptors).

Comment: Process address-space isolation isn't one of those *"usefulness-versus-security tradeoffs"*. There is no tradeoff involved, at all. Address-space isolation is a virtualization method that prevents independent processes from interfering with each other. It's not a security feature. Security is implemented by way of securing the kernel object that represents a process.

Comment: No, the trade-off I was thinking of is OpenProcess allowing for violating that isolation. It is not strictly required (in order to have a working system) but it makes many things much easier.

Comment: `OpenProcess` does the security checks based on the DACLs on the kernel object, not based on what you are going to do with the process handle. There is no trade-off. If you call it a trade-off, you aren't doing Windows' rights management system justice.